# How to use google maps script for android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

How do i use the google maps on android to get the same script as the website

I want it to search the nearest mcdonalds from the location and have all the markers from the website

https://mcdonalds.com.au/find-us/restaurants

Comment: Use Places API https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/ and places search https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search

Answer (score 0):

That is possible. You can do that using Google Places API and specify in the parameters for `types=restaurants`.

This is a tested example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=cruise&types=restaurant&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Now this will fetch all the restaurants in the radius you have defined in the proximity of your current location or the input location.

You can further filter results by writing code that checks if {name name = Mc Donalds} then only fetch the results else {do nothing}. This would give you results just for McDonalds in 500 meter of radius from the specified location.

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: How do i get the nearbysearch for the same as the mcdonalds website? how to get their script? because api is not accurate and have old chains but the results from mcdonalds website is 100% accurate

Comment: That is what I searched in the beginning.. but Mc Donalds API are not reliable, Google Places API are more reliable that them. This is the best possible answer I could search of!!